# rgdal not installing in R? "non-zero exit status?"

Tags: r, macos, rgdal

I am trying to install the package rgdal on a new MacOS 12.2.1. I have the newest version of R, and it has not been working much to my frustration. When I use the command "install.packages("rgdal")," a prompt is displayed: "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)" I've tried this multiple times, selecting both yes and no, because I really have no idea what this prompt even means. Anyways, R downloads a bunch of necessary packages with no problem, but then when it gets to the end of the downloading process, this displays:

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal’
* restoring previous    ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/t5/dqf_shjn2v79xfnycl1thkxh0000gn/T/Rtmpz3gATu/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgdal") :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have no idea what this means! I'm tired, confused, upset, I have little experience with coding at all and yeah this is just not an ideal situation! If anyone with more experience with R understands what is happening, I'd love help!
Thank you!

Comment: It's likely that there is some failure in installing one or more dependencies. Sometimes installing the failed package independently solved this kind of problem. You showed only the last part of the messages so we cannot decide which part failed. Can you show all the messages that pop up during `rgdal` installation process?